# How do I export the predictions from XGBoost model?

Tags: python, output, export-to-csv, prediction, xgboost

I have trained my XGBoost classifier model and achieved an outcome on test data. I am able to calculate confusion matrix.
Now I need support exporting my test predictions at asset level. I want an output at asset level saying 123 ID - 1
234 ID - 0
and so on.

Even probabilities will do instead of 1 & 0, so that I can figure where my model is weak and dig deeper into model's performance.

How do I achieve that in python? Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
# import pandas as pd
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
    preds = predict(xgb.model, test_x)
    patient_id = test_x['patient_ID']
    dframe = pd.DataFrame(patient_id)
    dframe['Response'] = list(test_y)
    dframe['Prediction'] = list(preds)
    print(dframe)
```